# Libgdx ios deployment with Android Studio

Tags: ios, android-studio, libgdx

In libgdx wiki, it is described how to deploy to ios with eclipse and its plug-in. I use Android studio instead of eclipse. How can I deploy to IOS?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK to develop IOS platform you can use any editor you like but you will need Mac OS X (10.9+) or iOS device.